# Hypothesis test for a population proportion

Tags: statistics, binomial-distribution, hypothesis-testing

$H_0: $ the probability that a person has the characteristic A = $0.05$

$H_1: $ the probability that a person has the characteristic A $­\neq 0.05$

I take a sample of size $500$ and find that $40$ people ($0.08$) have the characteristic A. I want to test the null hypothesis with $\alpha = 0.01$.

First, I would have to find the sample's variance, which is $\dfrac{1}{500-1}(0.08-0.05)^2 = 0.0000018$, so the standard deviation is $0.00134$.

The discriminating function would be Student's T fonction. The observed T is $\dfrac{0.08-0.05}{0.00134}*\sqrt{500} = 499$. That means that the critical $\alpha$ value would be incredibly small. That seems a bit extreme, did I go wrong somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see how the t distribution is appropriate here.

**Test using normal approximation.** Using the normal approximation to the binomial, we have the
test statistic

$$Z = \frac{\hat \theta - \theta_0}{\sigma_{\hat \theta}},$$

where $\hat\theta = 40/500 = 0.08$ is the estimate of the
true population proportion $\theta$ having the characteristic.
Also $\theta_0 = 0.05$ is the hypothetical population proportion.
And, according to $H_0$, $\sigma_{\hat \theta} = SD(\hat \theta) = 
\sqrt{\frac{\theta_0(1-\theta_0)}{n}}.$

Then, assuming $H_0$ to be true, $Z \stackrel{aprx}{\sim} Norm(0,1)$
and we reject $H_0$ at the 1% level if $|Z| > 2.576.$

Because $\theta_0 = 0.05,$ we get 
$SD(\hat \theta) = \sqrt{.05(.95)/500} =  0.009745.$
So $$Z = (.08 - .05)/.009745 = 3.08$$ and We reject $H_0$ because
$|Z| = 3.08 > 2.576.$

The P-value in this situation is $P(|Z| > 3.08) =  0.0021.$

*Reference:* Except for notation, the exposition above follows very closely 
the explanation of the 'binomial test' in Ott & Longnecker, 7e, pp 488-489.
Perhaps your textbook contains something similar.

**Esact binomial test.** Here is printout from Minitab's 'exact' test procedure for this test,
which does not use the normal approximation. $H_0$ is rejected at
the 1% level because the P-value is less than 0.01. Also, notice
that the 99% CI for $\theta$ does not include 0.05.

```
 Test and CI for One Proportion 

 Test of p = 0.05 vs p ≠ 0.05

                                                    Exact
 Sample   X    N  Sample p         99% CI         P-Value
 1       40  500  0.080000  (0.051879, 0.116412)    0.005
```

Note: Requesting the normal approximation instead of the exact test
in Minitab, one gets P-value 0.002, which agrees with our result from
the normal approximation.

**Plot of BINOM(500, .05).** Perhaps more intuitively, here is a
plot of your hypothetical binomial distribution with $n = 500$ and $\theta = .05$ over the span of $x$-values where it has substantial probability.
Notice that your observed value $x = 40$ is very far out into the right
tail of this distribution. The exact P-value from Minitab is essentially
double the (very small) probability in this distribution to the right of $x = 40.$

[image]

*Addendum* (5 hrs later): Some users seem to be offended by *any computer code at all* on this site (perhaps
preferring duck quill pens and oxblood/charcoal ink on papyrus).
I try to keep blood pressures low by omitting detailed code for my graphs. But @Brandon has requested code for the plot above, so here it is.

```
 x = 10:45;  pdf=dbinom(x, 500, .05)
 plot(x, pdf, lwd=2, col="blue", type="h", ylab="PDF", 
     main="PDF of BINOM(500, .05)")
   abline(h=0, col="green2")
   abline(v=40, col="red", lty="dashed", lwd=2)
```

Comment: I can't find the formula for the standard deviation. Instead, I find that the variance is np(1-p). Why are we dividing by n?

Comment: Because that's how to find SE for normal distribution

Comment: @BruceET would prop.test in R not be useful here compared to the binom.test. I ran some examples(specifically  x = 44, n = 63 and p =.8) and prop.test yielded a p-value < .05 and the binom.test yielded a p-value > .05. Is this because of the exactness in binom.test? Is it because prop.test uses the Wilson and not the Wald, and is an approximation, not exact? I know in practice you could report both methods but I'm curious you're thoughts ? Sorry for all the questions

Comment: $Var(\hat\theta) = Var(X/n) = \frac{1}{n^2} Var(X) = \frac{n\theta(1-\theta)}{n^2} = \theta(1-\theta)/n.$

Comment: @Brandon: Sticking with the problem at hand, R's `binom.test(40,500,.05,conf=.99)` gives P-val .0038 and same 99% CI as MTB test for one prop. Controversy about P-val for 2-sided test: (a) double one-sided CI vs (b) check same dist away in both tails and add. // R's `prop.test` is more gen'l GOF test using chi-sq GOF statistic (1 cat var, fit to stated dist'n, as in checking fairness of die; 2 cat var, contingency table, test independence). Here it would use CHISQ(1) which is square of Z~std norm, but no simple continuity correction. Yates' cont corr has be shown to 'overcorrect'.

Comment: @BruceET Interesting and informative! Thanks for the response. Could you supply the code for the PDF? I am having trouble replicating it in R. I don't want to make these comments messy but I am using...                     x = 0:40;  pdf = dbinom(x, 40, .05)
plot(x, pdf,  ylim=c(0, max(pdf)),lwd=2, type="h", main="PDF of BINOM(500, .05)")
abline(h=0, col="green")

Comment: @Brandon: Code still lurking in my R Console window, so pasted it into Answ.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49577/discussion-between-brandon-and-bruceet).